# Can someone identify what's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a GUI that calculates the volume of a circle when the user inputs a radius. So far what I have is:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Volume
{
    //Creates a JFrame that calculates the Volume of a circle given the radius
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Volume Calc");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    VolumePanel panel = new VolumePanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

for my Jframe and:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VolumePanel extends JPanel
{
private JLabel radiusLabel, volumeLabel, resultLabel;
private JTextField inputField;

//Sets up the Panel
public VolumePanel()
{
    JLabel radiusLabel = new JLabel("Please enter the radius: ");
    JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("The volume of the circle is: ");
    JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("");

    JTextField inputField = new JTextField(5);
    inputField.addActionListener (new VolumeCalc());

    add (radiusLabel);
    add (inputField);
    add (volumeLabel);
    add (resultLabel);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,75));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

//Calculates the volume based on the input
private class VolumeCalc implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent stuff)
    {
        double radius, volume;
        String input = inputField.getText();

        radius = Double.parseDouble(input);
        volume = (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);

        resultLabel.setText (Double.toString(volume));
    }
}
}
```

for my Panel. It compiles fine and runs perfectly fine, but when I press the enter key it messes up.

Comment: "it messes up"

What actually happens? Can you clarify?

Comment: We are going to need a bit more info about what exactly is happening vs. what you expected.

Comment: So what I expected to happen was that the volume would be calculated and displayed in the resultLabel, but what happened is that the command prompt opened up and displayed a lot of errors

Comment: Once again, instead of saying something like "it displayed a lot of errors", just tell us what the errors were. They are usually VERY informative as to what the problem is.

Comment: By the way, "volume" is for 3-dimensional objects like spheres.  What you're computing here is called "area".

Answer (score 2):

You have two `inputField` declarations, and they declare separate variables.  This one:

```
private JTextField inputField;
```

is a member field of the instance, but it is never initialized, so it is always `null`.  This one:

```
JTextField inputField = new JTextField(5);
```

is a local variable inside the constructor.  It is visible *only* inside the constructor.  It goes away after the constructor is done.

If you want the constructor to modify the field, change the second line to

```
inputField = new JTextField(5);
```

which makes it an assignment statement, not a declaration of a new variable.

Answer (score -1):

in you actionPerformed try:

```
String input = inputField.getText(); // guessing your input is the size of the circle
int result = Math.PI * Integer.valueOf(input);
resultLabel.setText(result);
```

there is no volume in a circle since its flat

[Source](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/area-of-a-circle-calculator.html)

EDIT: with your code layout you should have an error when trying to use inputField & resultLabel in volumePanel

Comment: This is totally wrong.  You just changed the correct formula for "area" to an incorrect formula, and you changed his code that complies fine to something that doesn't compile because you can't multiply by a `String`, and you can't use `setText` on an `int`.